# In what ways are electric fields practically produced in a lab?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I have a specific example in mind: say we have an essentially flat non-conducting disk, and we want to put a charge distribution on it that is dependent on the radial position in a periodic manner. How would one practically put the charge on in this manner?

Comment: Place in vacuum. Spin around axis. Spray with electrons from an electron gun, varying current as you move across the radius.

Comment: Interesting. Is this actually used? Could you direct me to some articles?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [same sort of technology that is used in a photocopier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerography). Your flat disk (a drum in photocopiers) would be uniformly charged then illuminated with visible light where you want the charge to be reduced. The light renders the sheet conductive so the charge leaks away.

Given how routine photocopier technology is it is surely easily adaptable for your application.